# ¿Como capturar excepciones de mongodb en java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Hola tengo el siguiente código en el cual me conecto a la base de datos, pero no logro capturar las excepciones que presenta el driver de mongo de ninguna forma

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;

/**
 *
 * @author personal
 */
public class mongodb {

    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private MongoDatabase database;
    private MongoCollection<Document> collection;

    public mongodb() {

        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            database = mongoClient.getDatabase("ferreteria");

        } catch (MongoSocketOpenException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al conectarse con la base de datos");
        }
    }

    public MongoCollection<Document> getCollection(String tabla) {

        try {
            return collection = database.getCollection(tabla);
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mongodb conexion = new mongodb();

       MongoCollection<Document> productos = conexion.getCollection("productos");
//        Document doc = new Document("name", "MongoDB")
//                .append("type", "database")
//                .append("count", 1)
//                .append("versions", Arrays.asList("v3.2", "v3.0", "v2.6"))
//                .append("info", new Document("x", 203).append("y", 102));
//        productos.insertOne(doc);
//        List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
//        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
//            documents.add(new Document("i", i));
//        }
//        productos.insertMany(documents);
    }

}
```

Comment: Te refieres a que no logras obtener el mensaje de error? Cual es el problema?

Comment: Que quieres hacer, que no te funciona, que esperas ver, que es que no ves? Para empezar no deberías implementar un método que devuelve **null** en caso de una _MongoException_ sin ninguna entrada en un log o mensaje de error, y luego usar el resultado sin chequeo si es **null**. Chiquillos, traten de aprender de no ofuscar errores.

Comment: Quiero capturar las excepciones para poder devolver mensajes y no se congele el programa @Elenasys

Comment: @StefanNolde, no hago las llamas ni validaciones en la misma clase, el problema es que la MongoException  no salta en ningún momento y no retorna null, pero igual se presenta una Excepción

Comment: Sal de dudas. Utiliza Exception que es genérico y obtén el tipo de error para ver cuál se está lanzando.

Answer (score 0):

Estas atrapando excepciones propias de MongoDB como son `MongoSocketOpenException` y `MongoException` :

```
try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
            database = mongoClient.getDatabase("ferreteria");

        } catch (MongoSocketOpenException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al conectarse con la base de datos");
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            return null;
        }
```

Probablemente se estan generando otro tipo de excepciones, puedes agregar:

```
  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error "+ e.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: intente capturarlas de esa forma pero tampoco funciona, siguen apareciendo excepciones y catch no las captura

Comment: _Exception_ es la superclase de todas excepciones, así si lo tienes en el ultimo catch (a lo mejor con un _e.printStackTrace()_) no es posible que no los capturas. Si no los capturas, significa que se producieron en otra parte, donde no tienes _try - catch_. Aparte de eso ayudaría de compartir el stacktrace de las excepciones no capturados con que el programa termina. Así supieras donde se produce el error..

Comment: Al parecer las Excepciones con el driver de mongo en java se trabajan en hilos independientes por lo cual no los puedo capturar de esa forma

Comment: Volvemos al principio. Coloca _e.printStackTrace()_ al principio de **cada** bloque catch que estas usando. Luego revisa si tienes excepciones en el log. Si no tienes nada, implica que todo**debería** funcionar como corresponde, si no lo hace, tenemos un tremendo problema con _MongoDB_